# Blender-Cycles rendering output black for certain parts

Tags: rendering, blender

I am using cycles for rendering. In viewport shading some parts shows black.. But when I render the same in cycles.. some other parts will display black in rendered image. Even though there is no overlaping and duplicate objects.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn2RA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbAZp.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlOgm.jpg)

I am expecting this image without black color. I tried to enable material override. but it did not work. Please help to solve this issue.